# Q: Digital potentiometer MCP4162

Tags: integrated-circuit, register

I am having a hard time understanding the [MCP4162](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22059b.pdf) Datasheet.

The application for the digi pot is have an Ardunio to control the wiper resistance so I can have a constant desired output voltage regardless of input signal. So depending on the input signal the digipot will find the ideal resistance to get close enough to the target output voltage of 1.98V.

Example: Set Output Voltage = 1.98V

Input = 1.414Vp

\$Digi pot = ((\frac{V_o}{V_in})-1)*R1\$

\$Digi pot = ((\frac{1.98}{1.414})-1)*1000\$

\$Digi pot = 400\Omega\$

Input = 0.5Vp

\$Digi pot = ((\frac{V_o}{V_in})-1)*R1\$

\$Digi pot = ((\frac{1.98}{0.5})-1)*1000\$

\$Digi pot = 2960\Omega\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe2RAV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have read the datasheet multiple times and I still don't which register is the one I need to be changing.

The one I would assume is the 0x04 address where it's described below. The datasheet only tells you about 2 registers and what their bits do when you write into them.

and I dont understand the equation stated in the datahseet that tells you the output resistance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *which register is the one I need to be changing* - that would depend on what you want to achieve...

Comment: Sorry about that, The application I am trying to use it for is an non inverting amplifier and putting digi pot in the negative feedback loop so I can have a constant gain.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have inserted a schematic of what I want to do with the chip.

Comment: Something is wrong.  If your pot were a simple resistor, you would have a constant gain.  I think you are trying to build an adjustable gain amplifier, but your question, as is, does not make sense.

Comment: Oh man no no you're right. It doesnt make sense. I meant a constant output Voltage, regardless of input signal.

Comment: No problem -- Just edit your question.  There should be an edit link right below your topic tags

Comment: Corrected, let me know if that makes more sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the datasheet, you're going to want to write to Volatile Wiper 0, and 1.

The TCON Register is used for configuring how the devices outputs are connected, you'll probably have to set that up on powerup. Although the defaults might be ok.

You can ignore the non-volatile variables. Those are used if you want to program the chip and then run it without a micro attached.

Comment: OH! How did you figure that out? For the life of my I couldn't find out how... Do you know how to translate the byte into the register for the desire resistance?

Comment: "A  value  in  the  volatile  wiper  register  selects  which
analog  switch  to  close,  connecting  the  W  terminal  to
the selected node of the resistor ladder." It's on page 36 of the datasheet. ..yeah these datasheets are terrible for newbies.

Comment: Ahh I see, and yeah I would have to agree.

would you know what to do with the equation on page 35 & 36? Also by the looks of it, its a 9 bit register do you know for example the resistance value if I put like 0x03 into it?

Comment: I would say that R = (Rab*3)/256 + 75Ohms. So you need to know the Rab resistance. What is the number after mcp4162 (103 or what)? But do not forget that the Rab resistance tolerance is +/-20%

Comment: Yeah that's where I get confused, what is Rab? you mean the 1k?

Comment: Oh it looks like you can preset Rab?

Comment: No, you cannot preset Rab resistance. You can buy MCP4162 with a specific Rab resistance (the maximum resistance your digital potentiometer can have).  5K, 10k 50k, or 100k. To see which one you have, you need to read the marking on the IC after the MCP4162- (502 or 103 or 503 or 104). Do you understand now?